# command prompt says "No such file or directory" but the file exists

Tags: python-3.x, bash

I'm having a problem with running files in command prompt, keeps saying "no such file or directory"

I copy n pasted a pathway for an existing file and just swapped the file with the one that im being told does not exist. Tried various small changes in syntax as well.

in text editor:

```
from sys import argv
script, filename = argv
txt = open(filename)

print(f"heres the file you wanted:{filename}:")
print(txt.read())

print("type the filename again:")
file_again=input("> ")

txt_again=open(file_again)
print(txt_again.read())
```

in BASH:

```
python3.7 /users/philipedwards/Documents/ex15.py test.txt
```

Comment: The simple explanation is usually that the file simply doesn't exist. What file name did you pass in and how can you prove to yourself and to us that that file really exists? Sometimes beginners have strange and wonderful conceptions of how to understand file names.

Comment: Also, can you please [edit] the question to show the full traceback? Is it the first or the second `open` which fails?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming `test.txt` is in the `Documents` folder. But, based on this command:

```
python3.7 /users/philipedwards/Documents/ex15.py test.txt
```

your current location might *not* be the `Documents` directory. By specifying `text.txt` you're trying to open `text.txt` from the current directory, *not* `/users/philipedwards/Documents/test.txt`.

So, either run the script from the `Documents` directory:

```
cd /users/philipedwards/Documents
python3.7 ex15.py test.txt
```

Or if you don't want to change the active directory, specify the full path of the text file:

```
python3.7 /users/philipedwards/Documents/ex15.py /users/philipedwards/Documents/test.txt
```

Comment: This is probably correct, but you can't tell what the current location is based on that command. It could be root or it could be anything else.

Comment: @gihr, I tried the last one with including both pathways and that worked, its weird with the exercises im taking the instructor just types the filenames in and it works but I have to type the full path, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Philbus That's probably because the instructor is running the script from the same directory as the file. Please consider marking my answer as accepted (check mark on the left) since it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

For futur persons facing this problem. It's maybe because of the binary wich is 32Bits or any incompatible architercture.
Here is an excellent thread referencing the same problem:
[No such file or directory? But the file exists!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Pointing that the architecture maybe the source of the problem is the solution. The link is just additional info.